# Moved server, changed nameservers

Tags: dns-hosting

So we wanted to move a server, previously hosted and maintained by a large company. If we wanted to move the server we'd have to switch registrars as well.

So i moved everything to a new server, tested if it worked by editing my hosts file, worked fine, so figured it wouldn't be to much trouble to switch registrars. Made an account at a registrar (gandi, but it shouldn't matter?), using gandi's nameservers. Got my 'zone file' set up, and transfered the domain. To my surprise, the site went off.

So I just hope to get some clarification on this.

1. It shouldn't matter what nameservers I use, as long as they're valid and I own the domain, correct?
2. How can the site go offline? It was my understanding that either the DNS would point to the new entry, or the old, but never 'not exist', so what's happening there?
3. The only real settings i need on the Registrar zone are

   domain.net 3600 IN A xxx.xx.xxx.xx
   www.domain.net 3600 IN A xxx.xx.xxx.xx

correct? Is there other settings  (CNAME/MX) that would interfere with this basic functionality?

4. How long can the site be off like this?

You may have noticed I'm panicking a tiny bit, even though i -think- all it needs is time to propagate, but I'd like to be sure, and any answers would be very comforting right now. Another thing i think is odd and sometwhat worrying is that if i do nslookup domain.net a.dns.gandi.net (primary nameserver im using) it gives 'can't find: no answer', any answers/wisdom would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: further information, i started the move about an hour ago.

Comment: The problem with your question, as is the case with so many other DNS questions here, is that you've omitted the actual domain name. We couldn't possibly offer any advice or answers other than: `"Duh, I don't know. It could be anything"` - How about doing us and yourself a favor and tell us what the actual domain name is so that we can try to help?

Comment: @joeqwerty interactie-academie.be is the actual domain name, it used to be hosted on 5.134.1.127 and now it should be on 153.92.127.223. It's supposedly using gandi's nameservers which are a.dns.gandi.net // b.dns.gandi.net // c.dns.gandi.net

Comment: DNSstuff reports that you have no A records - http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=interactie-academie.be

Comment: So I'm guessing that your assumption when you moved the domain to the new Registrar was that the zone file with it's DNS records would move with it. That's not the case. You need to create the DNS records at the new Registrar.

Comment: @joeqwerty I do though, or well, i should have.. for interactie-academie.be, www.interactie-academie.be and @ (very recently)

Comment: Log into your DNS management portal at the new Registrar and check your DNS records.

Comment: @joeqwerty check screenshot i pasted in comment below hakan linkvists post

Comment: @DrunkWolf, I can access the site: interactie-academie.be, guess it took some time to update, or you have fixed the issue. Anyway your registrar was ok, but no record. So can only be a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the domain `interactie-academie.be` is delegated to `{a,b,c}.dns.gandi.net` (as mentioned in your question) and these nameservers do appear to have a `interactie-academie.be` zone but the records you mention (`interactie-academie.be A`, `www.interactie-academie.be A`) do not appear to exist in this zone.

```
$ dig @a.dns.gandi.net interactie-academie.be. A +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P3-RedHat-9.10.3-10.P3.fc23 <<>> @a.dns.gandi.net interactie-academie.be. A +norec
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64613
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;interactie-academie.be.                IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
interactie-academie.be. 10800   IN      SOA     a.dns.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net. 1456608542 10800 3600 604800 10800

;; Query time: 18 msec
;; SERVER: 2604:3400:abca::1#53(2604:3400:abca::1)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb 27 23:22:39 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113

$
```

Are you absolutely positive that you have added these records to the `interactie-academie.be` zone on the Gandi nameservers?

It appears that the names that actually have these `A` records are `www.interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be` and `interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be`.

Eg

```
$ dig @a.dns.gandi.net interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be. A +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P3-RedHat-9.10.3-10.P3.fc23 <<>> @a.dns.gandi.net interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be. A +norec
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59345
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be. 300 IN A 153.92.127.223

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
interactie-academie.be. 10800   IN      NS      c.dns.gandi.net.
interactie-academie.be. 10800   IN      NS      b.dns.gandi.net.
interactie-academie.be. 10800   IN      NS      a.dns.gandi.net.

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 2604:3400:abca::1#53(2604:3400:abca::1)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb 27 23:29:25 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 151

$
```

There appears to have been some confusion as to how Gandi expect the input, the names you entered were considered zone-relative while you expected them to be treated as absolute.

For the future, much like you mentioned testing that other services worked as intended before changing servers, I would suggest actually testing the new nameservers respond as desired before changing the delegation. (Eg `dig @new.nameserver.example example.com A +norec`, etc.)

Comment: I have A records (or should have, since i put them in my "zone" and am using that "zone" for the domain) for the domain, www.domain and now (very recently, as a friend suggested) for @

Comment: @DrunkWolf Can you elaborate on what you mean? The Gandi nameservers say that there are no such records.

Comment: screenshot of my settings http://imgur.com/hFEcoFI

Comment: @DrunkWolf It looks like you have `www.interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be` and `interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be`

Comment: I'm sorry can you elaborate, are you saying i should remove some of the records? what specifically is wrong?

Comment: @DrunkWolf I'm saying that I believe it was an accident that you added eg `www.interactie-academie.be.interactie-academie.be` instead of `www.interactie-academie.be`

Comment: update!: Now when i do a nslookup on gandi's nameservers, i actually get the right ip adress, so i think the @ was the fix i needed, do i not need the rest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36320/discussion-between-drunkwolf-and-hakan-lindqvist).

Comment: @DrunkWolf add a record for `www`?

Answer (score 2):

Your question rather implies that you don't fully understand how DNS works. It would have been helpful if you had supplied the real details about the website, it's IP address before and after and the hosting, then we could have assessed whether the currently published data matched what you think it should be.

While buying your hosting and DNS from the same provider can give a very small cost saving, as you have found out to your cost, it can create problems if/when you try to move your site.

> the site went off.

This is not a meaningful diagnosis.

Is the problem that the resolved IP address on the client you are using points to the old provider? Or is it pointing to the new provider and the webserver does not recognise the site name or is it failing to resolve an address?

You can find out what IP address is being returned for the name with nslookup. If your new nameserver is unable to find the records you are paying them to host, then you should be talking to their support people in the first instance. You can override the address returned by DNS by setting the address in your hosts file(to test the hosting).

BTW please don't start sentences with a conjunction.